# Get String Windows Phone 8.1 through Background Task

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I've finally got a background task working which can send Toast notifications to the foregroud. Unfortunately, I've run into an issue. My background task needs to check an rss feed for updates, but when I run

```
HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
string result = await hc.GetString("http://url.com");
```

Nothing happens after the GetString method is fired, not returns, it never jumps to the next line. I've also tried with `BackgroundDownload` and it's also just stopping like httpclient, when it's supposed to download?

```
StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;
StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("feed.txt");
BackgroundDownloader test = new BackgroundDownloader();
DownloadOperation operation = test.CreateDownload(new Uri("https://url.com"), file);
operation.Priority = BackgroundTransferPriority.Default;
await operation.StartAsync();
```

I've looked every where for answer to this, but I cannot seem to find one... So how do I get the string from a site, like I would with `hc.GetString("");`?

This is my code:

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
    int lastSeenNews = Convert.ToInt32(Settings.GetValue("lastNews"));
    int lastNews = 0;
    HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
    var rss = await hc.GetStringAsync("https://url.com");

    List<RSSItem> items = new List<RSSItem>();
    lastNews = items[0].id;
    if (lastSeenNews < lastNews)
    {
        int unreadNotifications = 0;
        List<RSSItem> unreadStatuses = items.Where(x => x.id > lastSeenNews).ToList();
        unreadNotifications = unreadStatuses.Count;
    }
    ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastText01;
    XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);

    XmlNodeList toastTextElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
    toastTextElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(Settings.GetValue("lastNews")));

    ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
    ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
    deferral.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Have you considered that `DownloadString` might be throwing an exception? Wrap it in try-catch and see what you get ...

Comment: Same same, never continues from there, sadly :(

Comment: @Romasz It's a dummy URL, it's not the actual url I use in my app :P

Comment: Yeah, right :) Nevertheless when you try with different url - does it work correct?

Comment: My app itself uses the same method, works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the background task is terminating because of the async call to `hc.GetString()`

You can fix this by requesting a `BackgroundTaskDeferral` - see step 4 in [this quickstart  about background tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977055.aspx) for a code example.

Comment: I think I am already doing that, I've added the run method above :)

Comment: I'm confused - why is that Run() method marked as async, but I don't see any await calls in there?

Comment: No problem. Hmm, if it's still doing the same thing (never coming back after the when you step over it), you might try putting the same code in a "real" app and seeing if it ever comes back.  You should also turn on being notified on first-chance exceptions to see if an exception is being thrown.